# I have to adjust p-value in One way ANOVA with 3 groups and 600 metabolites?

Tags: anova, p-value, bioinformatics, genetics

I have three groups: CC, CT and TT and 600 metabolites.

When I do a lot of t-tests, I have to adjust the p-value, for example with fdr, but when I do a ANOVA with 3 groups, have I to adjust the ANOVA p-value, or not?

If I try to correct, nothing is more significative.

Comment: ANOVA and FDR provided different levels of correction for multiple comparisons (FDR being stronger). The appropriateness of one vs. the other depends on your design details as well as your tolerance of Type I and Type II errors. Here's a question - are your 600 metabolites 600 different samples per group? Or do you have fewer samples, each of which have several different metabolites measured in them?

Comment: I have 600 metabolites and a group variable: CC, CT an TT, I have to perform an ANOVA to test differences between groups for 600 metabolites. Now, I have to correct the overall p-value for the multiplicity?

Answer (score 1):

If you did a separate ANOVA for each metabolite you must correct for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) to evaluate whether any of the ANOVA results is likely to be a true positive. The false-discovery rate (FDR) is what's typically used for this type of study. You don't need to restrict yourself to a FDR cutoff of 5%; you can use a higher value so long as you recognize that a correspondingly higher fraction of your "positive" results will then be false positives.

If you are talking about all 3 pairwise comparisons among your 3 groups in a single ANOVA, you also should correct for multiple comparisons. Such corrections are pretty standard; for example, [Tukey's "honest significant difference" test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) is provided by the `TukeyHSD()` function in R.

That said, I'm a bit concerned whether your metabolite data will be adequately handled by multiple separate ANOVAs, as you seem to have done. I suspect that there is a good deal of correlation among the metabolite values within each group, which separate ANOVA analysis for each metabolite won't take into account. You could investigate whether you could use a true multivariate (multiple outcome) regression. That can take such correlations into account and provide an estimate via ANOVA of whether your groups differ significantly overall. [These notes](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Multivariate-Linear-Models.pdf) illustrate the approach.

Metabolomics is outside my expertise, so for further information I recommend that you examine the [Bioconductor web site](https://www.bioconductor.org) for specialized tools designed to handle your type of metabolomic data.